# How do i use multiple animation one after another in android?

Tags: android, animation

i want to show an *image* is **rotating** for **10** sec and after it gets **faded** and move towards **right**.

```
ImageView i1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);

Animation a1=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.move);

Animation a2=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.clockwise);
```

i am really confuse how to use Animation a1 and a2 one after other;

Comment: Fine! What have you tried so far?

Comment: since my image is rotating but after that i don't know how to use fade effect on it and move it towards right.

Comment: Edit your question with some coding you have done so far

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like below:

```
// Your fade animation
AlphaAnimation fadeOutAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
fadeOutAnimation.setDuration(300);

// Your translate animation - move image to right
TranslateAnimation translateAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(float fromXDelta, float toXDelta, float fromYDelta, float toYDelta);
translateAnimation.setDuration(300);

// Create animation set and add both animations to run simultaneously.
AnimationSet animationSet = new AnimationSet(true);
animationSet.add(fadeOutAnimation);
animationSet.add(translateAnimation);

// Now set animatio  listener on your rotate animation
rotateAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        animationSet.start();   
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
});
```